# Randomize the food production in snakeGame

Tags: c++, sfml

I have tried to randomize the position of the food in the snakeGame with `std::mt19937` but i can't quite get what to put as a parameter in `snakeFood.setPosition()`

Here is what i have for now, and it doesn't work.

```
        auto seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::mt19937 mt_rand(seed);
        snakeFood.setSize(sf::Vector2f(5,5));
        snakeFood.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        snakeFood.setPosition(seed, seed);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you populating it with the `seed` instead of generated random values? Did you look at [examples using `std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)?

Comment: Tip: Don't use the time to seed things. Use `std::random_device`.

Comment: I thought it might give random numbers, i always had a tough time understanding examples on various cpp websites a i found them to strict and technical with little example. Although i haven't even tried with what you link so i will try what's been suggested and come back here with, hopefully, a solution.

Comment: Why would `seed` give random numbers when it's just a clock sample? Use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) as your first stop, and skip over the third-rate tutorial garbage that clutters up the search results. If you can rework this using the example given, it's worth adding as a self-answer.

Comment: Okay, i figured it out. It was less complicated that i anticipated. There will still need to be a couple of adjustments (drawing new food whenever snake eats it) but that will come later. Thanks.